# $u_{n}>u_{n+1}>0$ and $u_{2}+u_{4}+u_{8}+u_{16}.....$diverges. prove that $\sum \frac{u_{n}}{n}$ diverges.

Tags: calculus

$u_{n}>u_{n+1}>0$ and $u_{2}+u_{4}+u_{8}+u_{16}.....$diverges. prove that $\sum \frac{u_{n}}{n}$ diverges.
The only thing i found is that $\left | \frac{u_{2^{n+1}}}{2u_{2^n}} \right |>1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a hint:
$$
\underbrace{\frac{u_1}{1} + \frac{u_2}{2}}_{>\,2\cdot u_2/2} 
+ \underbrace{\frac{u_3}{3} + \frac{u_4}{4}}_{>\,2\cdot u_4/4} 
+ \underbrace{\frac{u_5}{5} + \frac{u_6}{6} + \frac{u_7}{7} + \frac{u_8}{8}}_{>\,4\cdot u_8/8} + \cdots.
$$
Do you see what I'm doing? You might find information about the [Cauchy condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) useful.

Comment: looks similar to the proof of why $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

Comment: Exactly. Do you think it converges or diverges?

Comment: Since it's actually larger than $\frac{u_{2}}{2}+\frac{u_{4}}{2}+\frac{u_{8}}{2}+\frac{u_{16}}{2}+\frac{u_{32}}{2}.....$ which diverges, I think it diverges.

Comment: That's right! (Except you want $u_2$ instead of $u_2/2$.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a general theorem if $a_n$ is decreasing both $\sum a_n$ and $\sum 2^n a_{2^n}$ converge or both diverge.